# How to unblock blocked IP address in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ip

I installed a Drupal 7 site on my local server just to learn,
After 10-15 incorrect log in attempts my local IP has been blocked.

> Sorry, too many failed login attempts from your IP address. This IP address is temporarily blocked. Try again later or request a new password.

Screenshot of my local site:

[image: Screenshot of my local site]

As per articles:

1. I erased `flood` table.

   `flood` Table:

   [image: Flood Table]
2. Checked `blocked_ips` and found nothing.

   `blocked_ips` table:

[image: blocked_ips table]

I want to remove the limit of failed login attempts block.

Comment: this can helps you https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181017/how-to-avoid-admin-account-to-be-blocked-for-all-ips-by-failed-attemps-to-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cleared flood table your user is unblocked for sure. However it seems that you  forgot your password just resend it again if you have mail server setup up in local. If not, Reset the administrator password with sql-query > https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428

Login Security module will allow you to control number of failed attempts before blocking https://www.drupal.org/project/login_security

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i did everything mentioned here and it didn't helped, Is there is any way to remove ip blocking system? ...... 

Comment: Hardly  it's in core inside user.module, first rule of Drupal is never hack the core :)
Just reinstall the Drupal by the looks of it it's plain as it could be...

Comment: Hardly it's in core inside user.module, first rule of Drupal is never hack the core :) Just reinstall the Drupal by the looks of it it's plain as it could be

Comment: Hardly it's in core inside user.module, first rule of Drupal is never hack the core :) Just reinstall the Drupal by the looks of it it's plain as it could be

Comment: Hardly it's in core inside user.module, first rule of Drupal is never hack the core :) Just reinstall the Drupal by the looks of it it's plain as it could be